# How to set marquee behaviour in android to alternate programatically

Tags: android, marquee

This is the code I am using but the behaviour of the marquee is that is scrolls. How to make it to alternate i.e. it moves from right to left and then left to right.

```
public void setMarquee(TextView textView) {
        textView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        textView.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
        textView.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
        textView.setSelected(true);
        textView.requestFocus();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Step1

create folder called  anim in res directory

### step 2

create slide_left.xml

### slide_left.xml

```
    <translate
        android:duration="3000"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0" />
</set>
```

### step 3

in main_activity.class

```
 LinearLayout mlayout =
     (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mlayout); // the view u want to animate
     Animation slide_left_anim;
     slide_left_anim=
    AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    R.anim.slide_left);
    slide_left_anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

     mlayout.startAnimation(slide_left_anim);
```